# What are these three indentations on the SBD's wing?

Tags: wing, aviation-history

I was looking at pictures of WWII planes and noticed that the SBD Dauntless had 3 indentations towards the tip of the wing. What were these for?

[image: SBD Dauntless]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to ["The Dauntless Dive Bomber of World War Two"](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Dauntless_Dive_Bomber_of_World_War_T.html?id=sotfC1gBbsoC&hl=en) by Barrett Tillman, they are "letter-box" anti-stall leading edge wing slots added to improve the planes stability when approaching the 78knot stall speed during landings (and take offs, actually.)

The initial versions tended to not be able to build up enough speed during the (catapult-less) take offs from the carriers of WW2, and would simply drop off the front edge of a carrier. Adding the three slots basically fixed (or lowered) the speed of stall.

Comment: Umm, you were right the first time.  Improving the stall speed means lowering it...

Comment: But why would that work? Does it increase surface area thus increasing lift?

Comment: @JonasG.Drange :) That sounds like an EXCELLENT question to ask...

Answer (score 18):

This is a better picture showing those *indentations* (or are they?):

[image: Douglas SBD Dauntless]
<sup>*[Image Source](http://www.aviation-history.com/douglas/sbd.html)*</sup>

They appear to be wing slots (or [leading edge slots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_edge_slot)). More details are [here](http://www.aircraftresourcecenter.com/awa01/501-600/awa537-Dauntless-Bailey/00.shtm) and [here](http://forum.warthunder.com/index.php?/topic/212068-1451155-sbd-missing-leading-edge-fixed-wing-slots/).

Comment: Well spotted!  The text mentions them on this page: http://www.aviation-history.com/douglas/sbd.html .  Prety sure you're right.